# Writing test cases for Math.Random(); codewars kata

Tags: javascript, testing, tdd

I am authoring my first simple Kata on Codewars.
The objective of the Kata is to fix the code.
This is the complete working solution,

```
function yourFutureCareer() {
  var career = Math.random();
    if (career <= 0.32) {
        return 'FrontEnd Developer';
    } else if (career <= 0.65) {
        return 'BackEnd Developer';
    } else {
        return 'Full-Stack Developer';
    } 
} 

yourFutureCareer();
```

This is initial solution the user will work on,

```
function {
var : Math.random();
    if (career <= 0.32) {
        return = FrontEnd Developer
     else if (career <= 0.65) 
        return : BackEnd Developer,
    } else {
        return 'Full-Stack Developer'
    }

    yourFutureCareer();
```

In order to publish the Kata, I have to provide Test Cases that will determine if the solution is valid or not.
I've tried writing a first Test Case,

```
Test.assertSimilar(yourFutureCareer(), yourFutureCareer(), 'true')
```

Sometimes the test fails,

> Expected: FrontEnd Developer, instead got: BackEnd Developer

Sometimes the test passes,

> Test Passed: Value == Full-Stack Developer

So, how to write test cases so that the solution can be validated? Any example code or sample would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` is an externality that you can not control in your tests, so you need to refactor so that you have a testable function that has deterministic behavior, e.g:

```
function determineCareer(career) {
    if (career <= 0.32) {
        return 'FrontEnd Developer';
    } else if (career <= 0.65) {
        return 'BackEnd Developer';
    } else {
        return 'Full-Stack Developer';
    } 
}

function yourFutureCareer() { return determineCareer(Math.random(0)); }
```

Then you can write tests for `determineCareer(0.32)`, `determineCareer(0.321)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `Math.random` function to determine values between, you cannot expect to get the same result to be return from your tests each time they have been ran. In developing, the best tests are used to determines changes to one parameter.

## Aim to:

1. Get the same expected result from each individual your test you make, so try not use externalities, and avoid using `Math.random`
2. `Test.assertSimilar(actual, expected, msg)` where `actual` is the argument that is passed onto your function, `expected` is the correct value you assumed to returned by your kata, `msg`